# Save image visibility

Tags: pdf, diagrams

I write a document with a multiline textfield and three pictures.
The pictures change visibility if clicked. But if visibility of the pictures is changed when viewing the PDF, and the document is then saved, the picture changes are not saved to the file. Changes to the textfield are saved.

How to save the pictures visibility status?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{Form}
\TextField[multiline=true,width=\linewidth,height=50pt,value=Exampletext]{}
\end{Form}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {\begin{ocg}{Image 1}{ocg1}{1}\actionsocg{ocg1}{}{}{\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{example-image-a}}\end{ocg}};
\node at (0,1) {\begin{ocg}{Image 2}{ocg2}{1}\actionsocg{ocg2}{}{}{\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{example-image-b}}\end{ocg}};
\node at (0,2) {\begin{ocg}{Image 3}{ocg3}{1}\actionsocg{ocg3}{}{}{\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{example-image-c}}\end{ocg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems to be question about the PDF viewer you are using. The visibility state that you want to save does not exist at compile time, and I don't think there is any way to facilitate saving it from within LaTeX. Maybe try a forum for the PDF viewer software in question?

Comment: I use evince to view the PDF. When viewing a PDF I received from someone, it saves the visibility status changes. From this PDF I don't have the Source and it's made with other Software. When opening the file with Okular and 'view forms' option activated, checkboxes appear behind the images, just as like the checkbox status is somehow linked to the visibility status of the image. Or the image is somehow the checkboxsymbol of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Trick is to

- draw the CheckBox on top of the picture
- set background color transparent
- set color white
- remove border
- set symbol to rectangle
- enlarge font, so symbol fills whole box
- set size same as picture
- remove label from checkbox

Requires recent hyperref package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\TextField[multiline=true,width=\linewidth,height=50pt,value=Exampletext]{}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% get rid of label space
\def\LayoutCheckField#1#2{\makebox#2}

\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=0.7cm]{example-image-a}};
\node at (0,0) {
  \CheckBox[
    borderwidth=1,
    backgroundcolor=,
    color=1 1 1,
    bordercolor=,
    checkboxsymbol=\ding{110},
    charsize=100pt,
    checked=false,
    width=1cm,
    height=0.7cm
  ]{}
};  

\node at (0,1) {\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=0.7cm]{example-image-b}};
\node at (0,1) {
  \CheckBox[
    borderwidth=1,
    backgroundcolor=,
    color=1 1 1,
    bordercolor=,
    checkboxsymbol=\ding{110},
    charsize=100pt,
    checked=false,
    width=1cm,
    height=0.7cm
  ]{}
};  

\node at (0,2) {\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=0.7cm]{example-image-c}};
\node at (0,2) {
  \CheckBox[
    borderwidth=1,
    backgroundcolor=,
    color=1 1 1,
    bordercolor=,
    checkboxsymbol=\ding{110},
    charsize=100pt,
    checked=false,
    width=1cm,
    height=0.7cm
  ]{}
};  

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```